# Trying to build a Chrome Cordova App, but navigator is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, cordova

I'm building a Chrome Cordova App, and everything in the Chrome App APIs works just fine, but I'm trying to do some more advanced things, such as take a picture or read accelerometer data.

My app works just fine, but navigator seems to be undefined.

Here's a snippet of the code where I'm trying to access the accelerometer:

```
 $scope.picture = function(){navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration( function (acceleration) {
            alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
                  'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
                  'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
        },function () {}); }
    });
```

Here's some of the relevant logcat information:

```
D/CordovaLog(17498): chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/angular
.min.js: Line 86 : TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCurrentAcceleration' of und
efined
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at h.$scope.picture (chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodo
emajgpobgjngbdejp/controllers.js:31:53)
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/
angular.min.js:166:92
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/
angular.min.js:183:83
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at h.$eval (chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobg
jngbdejp/angular.min.js:104:370)
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at h.$apply (chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpob
gjngbdejp/angular.min.js:105:121)
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://kl
fmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/angular.min.js:183:65)
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (chrome-exte
nsion://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/jquery-1.9.1.js:3074:9)
D/CordovaLog(17498):     at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (chrome-extension:
//klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/jquery-1.9.1.js:2750:28)
I/chromium(17498): [INFO:CONSOLE(86)] "TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCurrent
Acceleration' of undefined
I/chromium(17498):     at h.$scope.picture (chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoem
ajgpobgjngbdejp/controllers.js:31:53)
I/chromium(17498):     at chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/an
gular.min.js:166:92
I/chromium(17498):     at chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/an
gular.min.js:183:83
I/chromium(17498):     at h.$eval (chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjn
gbdejp/angular.min.js:104:370)
I/chromium(17498):     at h.$apply (chrome-extension://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgj
ngbdejp/angular.min.js:105:121)
I/chromium(17498):     at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://klfm
kipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/angular.min.js:183:65)
I/chromium(17498):     at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (chrome-extens
ion://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/jquery-1.9.1.js:3074:9)
I/chromium(17498):     at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (chrome-extension://
klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/jquery-1.9.1.js:2750:28)", source: chrome-exten
sion://klfmkipmoapfodoemajgpobgjngbdejp/angular.min.js (86)
I/CordovaLog(17498): Found start page location: plugins/org.chromium.bootstrap/c
hromeapp.html
```

I understand completely that I'll need to use a Shim eventually, as navigator will only work on mobile. I'm just trying to get the mobile use case working first.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. (I've never used Cordova before). Apparently you have to install a plugin in order to get access to Cordova features. Now I know!

The fix was:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion
```